# How to select all text when Jetpack Compose OutlinedTextField gets focus

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How do I select all text when OutlinedTextField gets focus?

```
    @Composable
    fun SearchTextField(text:MutableState<String>,trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
                        placeholder: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = {Text(stringResource(R.string.vip_search_hint_sz))},keyboardOptions:KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions( keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number )){
        OutlinedTextField(value = text.value, onValueChange = {text.value = it},modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 5.dp,bottom = 5.dp),placeholder = placeholder,
            trailingIcon = trailingIcon,textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp),singleLine = true,colors = textFieldColors()
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val textFieldState = remember {
    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))
}

OutlinedTextField(
    value = textFieldState.value,
    onValueChange = { text -> textFieldState.value = text },
    modifier = Modifier
        .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
            if (focusState.isFocused) {
                val text = textFieldState.value.text
                textFieldState.value = textFieldState.value.copy(
                    selection = TextRange(0, text.length)
                )
            }
        }
)
```

Comment: thank you! but there is a little problem that the cursor must be at the end of text if i wanna select all text.